# use of Regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

While using Javascript, I'm making a limit for the product number in front-end.
The product number should be `xxxxx` 5 digits number or `xxx-xxx` style 6 numbers.

What I planned was replacing non-correct text characters to "" for each keypress 
and called in front like this `onkeypress = "checkonlynumdash();"`

for the function, my code is like below.

```
function checkonlynumdash() {
        e = window.event;
        var keypress = String.fromCharCode(e.keycode);
        var numdashkey = "";
        numdashkey = /^[-]|[^0-9-]/;
        return numkey.test(keypress);
}
```

while using window.event, I tried to control the real time keypress, but it 
does not seem working with replace. Hope someone can point out missing part.

Comment: Without putting my self in to this... You name the regex `numdashkey` in your example, and test against `numkey`... Error?

Comment: sorry it is just my fault, its numdashkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues:

```
e.keycode
```

I would change to

```
 e.charCode
```

and use another regex: `/[\d-]/`, it is more simple.
So the result might be:

```
function checkonlynumdash() {
        e = window.event;
        var keypress = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
        var numdashkey = /[\d-]/;
        return numdashkey.test(keypress);
    }
```

Also I can't understand your original regexp: `/^[-]|[^0-9-]/` symbol `^` means 'in the beginning of the string' or 'not'.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Simple Mask](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Simplest-Number-Input-Mask-Plugin-with-jQuery-Simple-Mask.html), it is jQuery plug-in to make masks on input fields. 
Usage:

```
$('input').simpleMask({
  'mask': ['####-####','#####-####']
});
```

[Demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simplest-Number-Input-Mask-Plugin-with-jQuery-Simple-Mask/)

Comment: well, trying to use regex is to avoid using other jquery, which sometimes causes problems.

Comment: in that case on key pressed you should verify all numbers from input (your product number). and if the number fits your regex then return true.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've missed some process. I still have question. The plugin you recommended, Simple Mask, does it work in IE 7? The website just mentioned IE 8+

Comment: try another [plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) it should work in IE7

Comment: Instead of jQuery, you could consider using the vanilla.js library, which is getting more and more popular: http://vanilla-js.com/

Comment: you could consider using the vanilla.js library too